# sqlsrv_query returns false without any error (sqlsrv_errors())

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

We have to execute an MSSQL stored procedure in order to insert a set of rows and return the result. The procedure is working perfectly as intended when executed inside the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. But it's not working when executed with `sqlsrv_execute` or `sqlsrv_query` in PHP. It's inserting only one row and returning no rows.

The Stored Procedure can be found [Here](http://pastebin.com/21FMNdat)

The PHP code is

```
//Here my SP required one argument. so i passed one argument. this @param and stored procedure argument name should be same(case sensitive)
$sql = " { call ResmaxCompareWithProduction ( ?,? ) } ";
$param1 = 'All';
$param2 = 'desk';
$params = array(array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),array(&$param2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql,$params);

if ($stmt===false) {
    // handle error
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
}else{
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)===false) {
        // handle error. This is where the error happens
        print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
    }
    else    
    {   
        $resultsetarr = array();
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }
        print_r($resultArray);
        // success! It never gets here, though.
    }
}
```

I tried to var_dump the result the procedure returned and it output `resource(4) of type (SQL Server Statement)`

The sqlsrv_errors() returns `NULL`

`sqlsrv_fetch_array` returned `boolean(false)`

I even tried using `sqlsrv_query` instead of `sqlsrv_prepare` and `sqlsrv_execute`, but same result.

Could you guys help me figure out what the issue is and make the procedure run as intended.